# Font too small for linux applications launched using Xming on windows

Tags: windows, fonts, ros, dpi, xming

I installed ROS under windows, following the instructions here: https://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows. However on running Ubuntu under windows and launching a GUI based linux application like rviz, the font size is too small to read.

Answer (score 1):

The applications are launched using Xming. Though it would seem that the Linux application is launched on windows, the truth is that they are being launched under xWindows, on windows. So changing the DPI of Xming will fix the font size in the application you launch.

To change the dpi of Xming, do the following:

1. Find the location of Xming. Do this by searching Xming in the windows search box. Right click on the Xming result and select "Open File location"
2. At the file location, right click on Xming and select properties. In the window that pops up, edit the contents of shortcut -> target to add in the dpi option. In my case the contents of target looked like this: "C:\Program Files\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow -nolisten inet6 -dpi 180
3. Restart Xming - to do this find it on the system tray on the bottom right of the screen. Restart Xming and try and start the offending application again. The font sizes will be larger